# Can I initialise and use USB-CDC purely in RAM?

Tags: c, arm, ram, iar

The chip is an Energy Micro EFM32380f1024 ARM microcontroller and I am using IAR ARM Embedded Workbench. I am aware of the __ramfunc directive however accomplishing initialising and accessing USB completely in RAM (as the flash is going to be completely erased) requires all USB libraries that will be used to be placed in RAM?

This will be used to upgrade the firmware on the microcontroller hence the flash erase. The USB is initialised and used (for normal use by the firmware) for serial communications. I do not wish to use the bootloader for firmware upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as the flash is going to be completely erased

Not a good idea. In case the update process fails to write the new program completely and the power is lost, your device will be **bricked**.

Using a bootloader is strongly recommended when you want the flash to be updatable by a user.